# How to use gnutv with dvb-c

Tags: tv

I was using `gnutv` with DVB-T for some years, just with the commandline

```
gnutv -channels ~/channels.conf -out file somefilename STATION_NAME
```

channels.conf generated by `w_scan -f c >channels_dvb-c.conf`

Now i got a DVB-C receiver (combined with -T and -T2). I ran

```
w_scan -f c >channels_dvb-c.conf
```

And got a nice channel list with a lot of cable channels. But gnutv doesn't work:

```
# grep arte channels_dvb-c.conf
arte;ARD:418000:M256:C:6900:401=2:402=deu@3,403=mis,407=mul,408=fra:404:0:28724:41985:1051:0
arte HD;Unitymedia:114000:M256:C:6900:513=27:514=deu@3,515=fra:518;1521,1522:0:17113:9999:121:0
# gnutv -channels channels_dvb-c.conf -out null arte
Unable to find requested channel arte
```

What is the problem? I do not see if there are any options for using dvb-c are needed, but on the other hand there do not seem to be many docs about gnutv and DVB-C.

Answer (score 1):

My command line for DVB-C looks like this:

```
gnutv -adapter 0 -frontend 0 -demux 0 -channels channels.conf -buffer 5000000000 -out file "output.ts" "arte HD"
```

This will record directly to the file `output.ts`.

I set the value for 'buffer' very high because I got errors while recording.

A line from my `channels.conf` (This is ONE line):

```
arte HD:114000000:INVERSION_AUTO:6900000:FEC_NONE:QAM_256:6661:6662+6663+6669:11120
```

The `channels.conf` file was created with the following command:

```
w_scan -fc -c DE -M > channels.conf
```

My Hardware is 'TT-TVStick® CT2-4400'.